# How to get a summay of non-numerical data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a summary table as follows:

```
A=
ID    Date      C1    C2
X     12/01/15  A     House
X     18/04/15  B     Rent
X     21/08/15  A     Rent
Y     01/08/15  C     Rent
Y     21/12/15  C     House

B=
ID    C1    C2     Data
X     3     House  12/01/15
Y     2     Rent   01/08/15

C=
ID    C1    C2    Date
X     3     Rent  21/08/15
Y     2     House 21/12/15
```

What it does is that for each ID, it counts the number of data entries (rows), in `B`, under column `C2` puts the first entry, and in `C` puts the last entry.

I can use the `groupby` fucntion and get the count, but don't know how to make column `C2`.

```
B = pd.DataFrame(A.groupby('ID', sort = False).count().ix[:, 1:]).reset_index(level=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also view the dates and columns side-by-side:

```
>>> (gb.first()
     .join(gb.last(), lsuffix='_first', rsuffix='_last'))
     .join(gb.C1.agg({'C1_count': 'count'}))

   Date_first C1_first C2_first Date_last C1_last C2_last  C1_count
ID                                                                 
X    12/01/15        A    House  21/08/15       A    Rent         3
Y    01/08/15        C     Rent  21/12/15       C   House         2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But how do I select to count items in `C1` and give first and last intances of columns `Data` and `C2`?

Comment: @Ana See amended response above.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first, last and count of each group:

```
grp = df.groupby('ID')
pd.concat([grp.first(), grp.last(), grp.size()], axis=1)

        Date C1     C2      Date C1     C2  0
ID                                           
X   12/01/15  A  House  21/08/15  A   Rent  3
Y   01/08/15  C   Rent  21/12/15  C  House  2
```

or, in separate `DataFrames`:

```
grp.first().join(grp.size().to_frame())

        Date C1     C2  0
ID                       
X   12/01/15  A  House  3
Y   01/08/15  C   Rent  2

grp.last().join(grp.size().to_frame())

        Date C1     C2  0
ID                       
X   21/08/15  A   Rent  3
Y   21/12/15  C  House  2
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, this answer is correct and clean, too.